# New to git. Testing branch wont merge with master, getting error Cannot Merge Binary Files

Tags: git

This is what it looks like : 
[image]

And so I did git status on both branches and they are all up to date and nothing to commit. According to bitbucket the 'stagingbranch' is 1 behind master and 6 ahead in commits. I use the master branch for my finished kind of work and stagingbranch for me to work on stuff that isnt complete since its the only way for me to sync my visual studio work between my laptop and pc. I finished the thing I was working on so I wanted to merge the stagingbranch which was ahead of master in commits to master so both were synced.

Comment: You should not include your compilation output in your source. Generally, you set up `.gitignore` to "hide" these changes from git so that they are not accidentally included. If you *do* have binary resources that *must* be source-controlled, then you need to be very careful that they are not modified in different branches at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might have Visual Studio open at the same time, so your files are locked by that.
But, the files you have conflict on should not be a part of your commit at all.  These are Visual Studio specific files and used by Visual studio while open.

What you lack is a .gitignore file. You should add this file, and you can do that either from Visual Studio itself, using the Team Explorer Settings/Repository Settings, and then use the Add gitignore there,  or download directly using e.g. curl like:

`curl -L -s https://www.gitignore.io/api/visualstudio`

That said, I assume you might have the files already in your repo, so the gitignore might ignore them first.  You should then delete them first.  Turn off VS, delete all the files that show up as conflict.  Best perhaps to delete them in both branches first.  You should then be able to merge it.

Comment: I added the gitignore via visual studio. What does it do? Also I checked task manager and there were no visual studio processes running.

Comment: The gitignore prevents those files from being added to your repository - but you need to delete them first.  After that they should not be added again.  Once they're gone, your build should work.